# Set intersection working, however printing all output instead of only the differences

Tags: python, set

I am getting the list of AWS resources that are tagged using `set.difference` to give me only the duplicates. This works, however when printing instead of getting only the differences I am getting all results.

Where am I going wrong with my script?

My code:

```
def extract_tags():

    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev-apps-read-only')
    client = session.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi',
                            region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('get_resources')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
    for page in page_iterator:
        for resource in page['ResourceTagMappingList']:
            resource_arn = resource['ResourceARN']
            tags_list = []
            for key_value_pair in resource['Tags']:
                key_name = key_value_pair['Key']
                key_value = key_value_pair['Value']
                tags_list.append(key_name)
                # list to check against the tag output from AWS

                mandatory_tags_list = [
                    "phx.tfe_workspace",
                    "aws.region",
                    "phx.bounded_context",
                    "phx.owner",
                    "phx.service_tier"
                ]
                # tag list from AWS. Variable declared in main loop above

        tags_list
        non_compliant_tags = ('Non-Compliant Tags:',
                              (set(mandatory_tags_list).difference(tags_list)))
        count = len(set(mandatory_tags_list) & set(tags_list))
        print(json.dumps(f'resource ARN: {resource_arn}'))
        print(json.dumps(f'{non_compliant_tags}', indent=2))
        print(count)


extract_tags()
```

My output gives me complaint resources and non-compliant resources. I only would like non-compliant resources:

```
Wrong:
"resource ARN:0a895d1c83fdbd76a"
"('Non-Compliant Tags:', {'phx.service_tier', 'phx.bounded_context', 'phx.tfe_workspace', 'phx.owner', 'aws.region'})"

Correct:
"resource ARN:e5b5ccfa-db6e-e027-9fab-0415d4958c30"
"('Non-Compliant Tags:', {'phx.service_tier', 'phx.tfe_workspace'})"
3
```

Comment: It seems like your printing it in the wrong scope, it should be in the next for loop. Also, `mandatory_tags_list` should not be defined in the inner most loop if you want to access it in the outer scope.

Comment: @mervin shashin i am still getting the same results. It still print all instead of just the differences 

i have move the print in to the next loop and aligned mandatory_tags_list outer. still give me the same results

Comment: `mandatory_tags_list` is still defined in the inner most loop. Since it's not a changing variable you could define it above the for loops. It would be more efficient! Also, you define `tags_list` in the second for loop, but try to print it in the first loop. You should shift the print statement into the second loop then. You need to learn how to define variables and access them in the correct scope. It's all over the place here.

Comment: works well now. move the mandatory_tags_list to the top.